# How to make multiple lists as wizard when the number of lists is unknown in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

what would be the best approach. I have a list in JSON with several different internal lists and need to present the different lists but at the same time and in the form of tutorial for you may be selecting one item from each list. I try with one `TableViewController` and make dynamic `NSArray` but without success. Also try to use the `STPopup` control, but this way is not dynamic because the amount of internal lists is unknown.

Json Structure

```
ItemOptionGroups: [
{
    Name: "Addon",
    Min: 0,
    Max: 0,
    TypeId: 0,
    Options: [ 
    {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "A",
        Price: 10.5
        },
        {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "B",
        Price: 14.75
        },
        {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "C",
        Price: 6.50
        }
    ]
},
{
    Name: "Sides",
    Min: 0,
    Max: 0,
    TypeId: 0,
    Options: [ 
    {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "X",
        Price: 31.5
        },
        {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "Y",
        Price: 40.75
        },
        {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "Z",
        Price: 60.00
        }
    ]
},
{
    Name: "Price",
    Min: 1,
    Max: 1,
    TypeId: 0,
    Options: [
        {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "12 oz.",
        Price: 3.5
        },
        {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "16 oz.",
        Price: 4.75
        },
        {
        Id: 0,
        Name: "20 oz.",
        Price: 6
        }
```

]
}

Comment: Post your code with `UITableView`. It is the best approach for this, unknown size array is fine for table view.

Comment: hi Max Iam travel right now I don't have the code but I can explain. I download the Json with AFNetworking and put the list to an array. Then aI have 3 Table View one for AddOns other for sides and other for Price and Then I call a STPopup and start the selection flow. But this is static If one more list was added I don't know how to show it because the unknow size of the array. Thanks

Comment: This is the control I use https://github.com/kevin0571/STPopup

Answer (score 0):

You could put your list in a UITableView where each cell of the tableview would be a UICollectionView containing all the items.

Comment: Thank Kujey for the comment. Do you have some sample code or app screenshot that implement this approach??